# Compile error when using AssemblyCopyrightAttribute or AssemblyCompanyAttribute via CodeDomProvider

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, codedom

I figure something silly is going on as the remaining assembly level attributes can be included just fine but whenever `AssemblyCopywriteAttribute` or `AssemblyCompanyAttribute` is declared it results in CS0116 and CS1730 errors.  Given that the code does not contain any method declarations I do not see how [CS0116](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx071h86.aspx) is applicable and there are no type definitions interspersed so not sure how [CS1730](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397584(v=vs.90).aspx) is applicable.

**Errors**

```
Error Number: CS0116
Error Text: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Error Number: CS1730
Error Text: Assembly and module attributes must precede all other elements defined in a file except using clauses and extern alias declarations
```

**Source File:**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]; // this results in a compile time error
[assembly: Guid("9d8271d9-957f-46dc-bcc6-1055137b4fad")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CCDA MAP")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("The mapping logic to source a CXD and populate a CCDA")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("My Company 2015")]; // this results in a compile time error
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.2.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.2.0.123")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("DEBUG")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadataAttribute("Built","06/27/2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadataAttribute("Host","JORMUNGANDR")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadataAttribute("The answer","42")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadataAttribute("Document Type","CCDA")]
[assembly: AssemblyMetadataAttribute("Document Spec Version","2.0")]
```

**Compilation Logic**

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
var source = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),"codedom"),"*.cs").ToList().Dump("Map Source").Select(i=>File.ReadAllText(i)).ToArray();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters{ GenerateInMemory = true, OutputAssembly = string.Format("Map.dll",count),TreatWarningsAsErrors = true, WarningLevel = 4};
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused by erroneous semicolons in the text:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("My Company 2015")]; // this results in a compile time error
```

Should be:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("My Company 2015")] // this does not result in a compile time error
```

And:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")]; // this results in a compile time error
```

Should be:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My Company")] // this does not result in a compile time error
```

Removing them clears up the errors you're seeing.